how can load the dynamic form after one click again in JQUERY?
this is my script to load a partial form for adding new address:
 function handleLocationChange() {
     var selectedLocationId = $(this).val();
     var subLocationSelect = $(this).closest("form").find("#SubLocation_Id");
     subLocationSelect.empty();

     // That was fist script for showing for 1 page ( not Dynamic form)
     $.ajax({
         url: "/UserPanel/Home/GetDistrictGroup/" + selectedLocationId,
         type: "GET",
         dataType: "json", // Specify JSON dataType
         success: function (data) {
             $.map(data, function (item) {
                 subLocationSelect.append('<option value=' + item.locationId + '>' + item.stateName + '</option>');
             });
         },
         error: function () {
             alert('Error occurred while loading districts.');
         }
     });
 }



 //** For Show click on AddNewAddress for First Form & reload partial Form again

 $(document).ready(function () {

     // Handle initial and dynamic forms change event in Location_Id  of form
     //.on is an order: change event on dynamic element: Here is Location_Id  in handleLocationChange:

     $("#addNewAddressContainer").on("change", "#Location_Id", handleLocationChange);   // First was " $("#btnAddNewAddress").click(function () " But change for changing and LocationId

     // Click event for adding new address
     $("#btnAddNewAddress").click(function () {
         var url = $(this).data("url");
         $.ajax({
             url: url,
             type: 'GET',
             success: function (data) {
                 $("#addNewAddressContainer").empty().append(data);
                 // Bind change event for Location_Id in dynamically loaded form
                 $("#addNewAddressContainer").find("form:last #Location_Id").change(handleLocationChange);
             },

             error: function () {
                 alert('Error occurred while loading the form.');
             }
         });
     });

after load the form I have some operation like add new address in data base and return to page and update view with ajax.
but after finishing the submit ion , the button does not work again, it means if I click on it it does not work . how can I handle it work in all status , before click and submission and after it ?
     // Handle form submission AddNewAddress Form

     $("#addNewAddressContainer").on("submit", "form", function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();

         var $form = $(this);
         var formData = $form.serialize();

         $.ajax({
             url: $form.attr("action"),
             type: $form.attr("method"),
             data: formData,
             success: function (response) {
                 if (response.success) {
                     ShowMessage(response.message); // From My ShowMessage Method
                     $form.hide();

                     $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');

                     // بعد از اضافه شدن آدرس جدید، لیست آدرس‌ها را به‌روزرسانی کنید
                     fetchAndUpdateAddressList();
                 } else {
                     ShowMessage(response.message);
                 }
             },
             error: function () {
                 ShowMessage('Error occurred while submitting the form.');
             }
         });
     });


     function fetchAndUpdateAddressList() {
         $.ajax({
             url: '/UserPanel/Home/GetClientContactInfoById', // تغییر دهید به کنترلر و اکشن مناسب
             type: 'GET',
             success: function (addresses) {
                 console.log(addresses); // بررسی کنید که آیا داده‌ها به درستی دریافت می‌شوند
                 var $addressListContainer = $("#addressListContainer"); // Select the container where addresses are displayed
                 $addressListContainer.empty(); // Clear the current list



                 // Check if there are addresses
                 if (addresses.length > 0) {
                     addresses.forEach(function (address) {
                         // Check for undefined values and set default values if needed
                         var addressValue = address.address || '';
                         var stateValue = address.state || '';
                         var districtValue = address.district || '';
                         var zipCodeValue = address.zipCode || '';
                         var locationIdValue = address.locationId || '';

                         var addressHtml = `
                                 <div class="row mb-3">
                                     <div class="col-lg-12">
                                         <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                             <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                 <div class="input-group-text">
                                                     <input type="radio" name="CartAddresses" value="${locationIdValue}" checked>
                                                 </div>
                                             </div>
                                             <input type="text" name="address" class="form-control" placeholder="Address" value="${addressValue}" readonly="readonly">
                                         </div>
                                     </div>
                                     <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
                                         <div class="control-group">
                                             <label>State</label>
                                             <div class="input-group">
                                                 <select class="form-control" disabled>
                                                     <option disabled selected>${stateValue}</option>
                                                 </select>
                                                 <div class="input-group-append">
                                                     <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
                                                 </div>
                                             </div>
                                         </div>
                                     </div>
                                     <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
                                         <div class="control-group">
                                             <label>District</label>
                                             <div class="input-group">
                                                 <select class="form-control" disabled>
                                                     <option disabled selected>${districtValue}</option>
                                                 </select>
                                                 <div class="input-group-append">
                                                     <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
                                                 </div>
                                             </div>
                                         </div>
                                     </div>
                                     <div class="col-md-2 mb-3">
                                         <div class="control-group">
                                             <label>Zip Code</label>
                                             <input type="number" class="form-control" value="${zipCodeValue}" readonly="readonly">
                                             <span></span>
                                         </div>
                                     </div>
                                 </div>
                                 <hr/>
                             `;
                         $addressListContainer.append(addressHtml);
                     });
                 }

                 // Add the button to add new addresses
                 var addNewAddressHtml = `
                         <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-lg-12">
                                 <span class="font-weight-bold">
                                     <button id="btnAddNewAddress" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-url="/YourController/GetAddNewAddressForm">
                                         <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add New Address
                                     </button>
                                 </span>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                         <div id="addNewAddressContainer"></div>
                     `;
                 $addressListContainer.append(addNewAddressHtml);
             },
             error: function () {
                 ShowMessage('Error occurred while fetching addresses.');
             }
         });
     }


If you're recreating the button dynamically, use event delegation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements
